Landsat8 level 2 ST_B10 values don't make sense
I downloaded 24 ST_B10 files from Earth Explorer, but the values in QGIS make no sense for them to be in Kelvin, as I expected them to be. For example, File LC08_L2SP_013032_20230302_20230316_02_T2_ST_B10 has values ranging from 4844 to 37694. Clearly I am missing something!

Your image is very cloudy.

From the "Constraints and Caveats" section of the "Landsat Collection 2 Surface Temperature" page:

A known error exists in the surface temperature retrievals relative to
clouds and possibly cloud shadows. The characterization of these
issues has been documented by Cook et al., (2014).

You can check the QA band, but at a bare minimum, I recommend checking the thumbnail image before you download.
For non cloudy data, see page 12 Table 6-1 of the Landsat 8-9 Collection 2 Level 2 Science Product Guide which shows the data values have a scale factor and offset applied to convert them to UInt16 values. For conversion see How do I use a scale factor with Landsat Level-2 science products?:

Surface Temperature
Landsat Collection 2 surface temperature has a scale factor of
0.00341802 and an additional offset of 149.0 per pixel.
For example, a pixel value of 44,947 is multiplied by 0.00341802 for
the scale factor and 149.0 is added for the additional offset to get
302.6 Kelvin after the scale factor is applied.

So you could use the QGIS Raster calculator to apply this conversion.


@TaylorRubin Does this answer your question?
